# Segmentation fault:Why the array index here goes out of bounds?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector

I was trying to solve the problem here- https://www.codechef.com/APRIL19B/problems/FENCE and initialized the array to 0 but when I try to access the value at arr[0][4] with n=4 and m=4, it prints a garbage value.

I tried to initialize using vector thinking I'm making some mistake in the initialization of array, it works for the sample testcase but still gives segmentation fault.

Here is my code -

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        long long n,m,k,res=0;
        cin>>n>>m>>k;
        //vector<vector<long long>> arr(n+2,vector<long long>(m+2,0));
        long long arr[n+2][m+2]={0};
        long long vec[k][k];
        for(unsigned int it=0;it<k;it++){
            int t1,t2;
            cin>>t1>>t2;
            arr[t1][t2]=1;
            vec[it][0]=t1;
            vec[it][1]=t2;
        }
        cout<<"values:"<<arr[1][4]<<endl;
        for(unsigned int itr =0;itr<k;itr++){
            int j = vec[itr][0];
            int i = vec[itr][1];
            //cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
            res+=4-(arr[i-1][j]+arr[i+1][j]+arr[i][j-1]+arr[i][j+1]);
        }
        cout<<res<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**
The sample input is:

```
Example Input
2
4 4 9
1 4
2 1 
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 3
4 1
4 2
4 3
4 4 1
1 1
Example Output
20
4
```

The constraints:

```
  1≤T≤10 
  1≤N,M≤10^9
  1≤K≤10^5
  1≤r≤N
  1≤c≤M
  the cells containing plants are pairwise distinct
```

I expect the output to be- 20 for the first testcase but get garbage value.

Comment: With the program constraints it's very easy for `arr` or `vec` to exceed the available Automatic memory. One of the reasons Variable Length Arrays are nor supported by Standard C++. Consider using a [matrix class like this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op) instead.

Comment: Also don’t include `bits/stdc++.h` or use `using namespace std`, they are very bad practice. And definitely don’t use `long long` it all you’re storing is a Boolean value.

Comment: The really funny thing about `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is `<iostream>` is also included. This suggests a bit of [Cargo Cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). `bits/stdc++.h` is an implementation-specific header designed to aid precompiled headers by including the entire standard library. Some folk saw this as a way to avoid having to include what they need included and as a result have slower-to-compile code that is non-portable. Not particularly good thinking.

Comment: Additionally, always check user inputs for consistency (e.g. t1 and t2 being smaller than k).

Comment: @JeJo, The constraints of the problem prevents that. Here are the constraints 1≤T≤10 
1≤N,M≤109
1≤K≤105
1≤r≤N
1≤c≤M

Answer (score 0):

When [declaring an array in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array), its size must be a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) - that is, the size must be known at compile time. Your compiler ought to be complaining about these lines because `m`, `n`, and `k` are uninitialized (more correctly, initialized to indeterminate values) at compile time:

```
long long arr[n+2][m+2]={0};
long long vec[k][k];
```

Comment: It won't complain. `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` pretty much ensures g++ compiler, and g++ allows Variable Length Arrays. Because of the VLAs, the asker's code will be almost certainly be running off the end of the stack for later test cases though.

Comment: I said "ought to" because VLAs are forbidden by definition in standard C++. As stated, array size must be a constant expression ([\[dcl.array\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.array#1)), and constant expressions must be evaluable at compile-time ([\[expr.const\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const)).

Comment: Not arguing that. VLAs make bad programs about a half-dozen ways when the compiler allows them. This compiler allows them, and they're almost certainly the cause of the segfaults when they exceed the stack space. Your answer doesn't address that. Not using the VLAs is sound policy, but for a good answer you should explain why they are a problem here and provide an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think that array is getting out of bounds in arr[i-1][j] or arr[i+1][j] or arr[i][j+1] or arr[i][j-1] that why the error is coming.

Comment: In the example set the array bounds are not breached. The math is just wrong. The asker has multiple problems including (Wait for it!) Stack Overflow.